# Generate data class attribute value only during creation

Tags: kotlin, jdbi, data-class

I have a data class `Supplier` defined in my models:

```
data class Supplier (
        val id: Int = 0,
        val name: String,
        val owner: String,
) {
    companion object {
        private const val prefix = "SUP"

        private fun generateId(): String {
            return prefix + UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        }
    }

    val supplierId = generateId()
}
```

I have a generated `supplierId` to generate a new identifier for each supplier that is created.

Once I create a new `Supplier` and save to a database, the `supplierId` is stored.

---

The issue is when I want to query a Supplier object based on an id provided by the user. The Dao implementation of the query function:

```
@SqlQuery("select $SUPPLIER_COLS from $TABLE_NAME where supplier_id = :supplier_id")
fun getSupplier(@Bind("supplier_id") supplierId: String): Supplier?
```

This function gets the correct row from the database, but when it returns the object by generating one again, a new `supplierId` is generated as part of it.

---

How do I modify my implementation such that the generator works only for the first time and not when reading from the database.

One way I can think of it is to generate the id before creating the object and pass that as a parameter. Doing this would mean that my class signature will not immediately tell me what is a generated field and what is not. Is there any other approach I can take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make `supplierId` as a constructor parameter with the default value like this:

```
data class Supplier(
    val supplierId: String = generateId(),
    val id: Int = 0,
    val name: String,
    val owner: String
) {
    companion object {
        private const val prefix = "SUP"

        private fun generateId(): String {
            return prefix + UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        }
    }
}
```

If you are using jdbi/kotlin `RowMapper` it should work with no additional changes.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `supplierId` is not a constructor argument the DAO implementation doesn't know how to set the value. Probably it's creating the object by calling the constructor. When creating the new object a new `supplierId` is generaged.

Either you have to add `supplierId` as a constructor parameter or set the value after the object is created. Since you already know the `supplierId` is belongs to this object, you can assign the value after the object is returned by DAO.